# SAGE: factorize characteristic polynomial in SR base ring

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, polynomial-math, factorization

I am total newbie to SAGE so this question might be trivial. How can I factorize the characteristic polynomial obtained by a symbolic matrix in SAGE 8.6? Is there a workaround to the fact that `factor()` is not defined on the base ring `SR` (see [here](https://members.loria.fr/pzimmermann/sagebook/polynomes.pdf)) which is the one inherited from the symbolic matrix?

For example I have in a SAGE/Jupyter notebook something like:

```
a,b,c = var('a','b','c')
M = Matrix(SR,3,3)
M[0] = [a, -b, 0]
M[1] = [c, a+b, 0]
M[2] = [0, 0, 1]
e = M.eigenvalues()
f = M.charpoly()
factor(f)
```

The last instruction raises a `NotImplementedError`.
In my real problem I am computing characteristic polynomials of large (8x8) symbolic matrices and I would like to get at glance all the factors, so as to quickly isolate negative real roots and instead easily discuss conditions for existence and sign of symbolic ones.

Comment: The short answer is that such *symbolic* factorizations can be pretty hellish ...

Comment: More seriously, this was also asked (and has an accepted answer) at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/45249/factorize-characteristic-polynomial-in-sr-base-ring/

Comment: Thanks @kcrisman. Actually the person that posted that question is the same one that posted it here (before figuring out that SageMath uses its own support forum).

Comment: Yes, I figured that was implicit in my comment :) I just like to make sure that if someone stumbles on a question on SO then they can easily find the answer if it exists.  Hope you enjoy using Sage!